export classでのfriend宣言が効かない
２つのC++ソースがこうなっていて
//  t1.cpp
export  module  mylib;

export  class   test
{
    friend  void    func();
    int     private_data;
};

//  t2.cpp
import  mylib;

void    func()
{
    test    obj;
    obj.private_data = 1;    //error
}

コンパイルするとエラーが出ます。
d:\test> g++ t1.cpp t2.cpp  --modules-ts -std=c++23 -c
t2.cpp: In function 'void func()':
t2.cpp:6:9: error: 'int test@mylib::private_data' is private within this context
    6 |     obj.private_data = 1;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In module mylib, imported at t2.cpp:1:
t1.cpp:6:13: note: declared private here
    6 |     int     private_data;
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~

コンパイラのバージョンはこうなっています。
d:\test> g++ --version
g++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

なぜ？　エラーを回避する方法があれば教えて下さい。

t1.cpp で friend 宣言された func は mylib モジュールに属していますが、 t2.cpp で宣言・定義された func がグローバルモジュールに属する別の関数となっているためです。
import mylib; とするのではなく module mylib; として t2.cpp を mylib のモジュールユニットとして認識させる必要があると思います。
